# Change the distance a modal UIViewController shifts up when the keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, modalviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that I'm presenting modally using the following code:

```
FeedbackViewController *fvc=[[FeedbackViewController alloc] init];
fvc.delegate=self;
[fvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When a UITextField in this modal view is tapped, the keyboard appears and the view animates up about 60 px. To ensure my text field is visible, I'd like the view to shift up 200 px instead. I know there are options for sliding the view around in a UIScrollView when dealing with multiple fields, but I'm wondering if there's not a more straightforward option for such a simple case?

Thanks for reading.

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION:**
I found a workaround that's currently working for me. My modal view controller is now full screen—essentially a white box on a translucent background—and I presentViewController without animation. Then, in the viewWillAppear method of the modal view, I fade in the translucent background and slide up the white box. The reverse is done when the modal view is dismissed. (This has the added bonus of an easily responsive background, e.g., for "tap to dismiss.")

Comment: There was a flag to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly basic solution: you can subscribe to the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification from NSNotificationCenter, and when you receive that notification you can shift your views out of the way with something like:

`self.viewToShift.frame = CGRectOffset(self.viewToShift.frame, 0, -100)`

or by changing it's position through any other manipulation of frame or layout constraints. You would also probably want to toss this into a UIView animation block.

you'll also want to subscribe to 'UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` so you can return to your original position afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem I've encountered with this approach is that there's already an animation happening when the user taps the text field—the keyboard is animating up ~60 px. Calling any code on the view's frame doesn't appear to have any effect while this animation is happening.

Comment: you're using layout constraints?

Comment: Auto Layout is unselected for this view. Also, interestingly, if I put a delay on the animation, say +100 px, the view immediately offsets by -100px when the keyboard first appears, and then after the delay it returns to its "normal" position.